# SDL MinGW Netbeans. <SDL/SDL.h> no such file or directory

Tags: c++, netbeans, compilation, sdl

## PROBLEM SOLVED

*Go to bottom to see the solution.*

Hello everybody i've been googling' looooong time and I didn't find anythinig, so, here we go:

I have this setup:

> Compiler: MinGW
>  IDE: Netbeans
>  Library: SDL
>  Language:
>   C++

Okey, so, i have included this folder: `"C:/SDL_1.2.15/include"` 
And Linked those libraries in this order:
-lmingw32
-lSDL_main
-lSDL

Then if I use a normal program without the `#include "SDL/SDL.h"` then compiles okeey.
So if i include the SDL header file the IDE gives me greenlight to compile an then, i get this output:

```
"C:/WinAVR-20090313/utils/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/pablo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SDL_Test'
"C:/WinAVR-20090313/utils/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/sdl_test.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `C:/Users/pablo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SDL_Test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe    -c -g -Wall -I/C/MinGW/include -I/C/SDL-1.2.15/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/pablo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SDL_Test'
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/pablo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SDL_Test'
main.cpp:11:21: error fatal: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
compilaci�n terminada.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

So! Here is the source code of my application, it only has a 'main.cpp' file:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: pablo
 *
 * Created on 1 de septiembre de 2013, 23:20
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;

}
```

I've found new issues; When I remove the #include (comment //) then the console throws me this errors instead the 'no such file or directory':

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDLmain
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL.dll
```

When I compile without #include  using Cygwin compiler, the project builds correctly.

Found another issue:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/C/SDL-1.2.15/lib/libSDLmain.a', needed by `dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/sdl_test.exe'.  Stop.
```

this happens when I add the full path to the SDL libraries instead of -lSDL.dll and -lSDL_main

**SOLUTION:**

```
The problem solves coping c:/SDL-1.15/include/SDL/ folder to c:/MinGW/include/ directory, and libraries from lib on c:/SDL-1.15/lib/SDL to MinGW/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the headers separately.
It's not enough to do the include, you have to do multiple things to add a thing like SDL in your project.

Comment: So what kind of headers?? the rest of the SDL include folder maybe? I tried to use Cygwin or Cygwin3 but both gives me lots of headaches and there's no tutorials about how to setup SDL with netbeans and MinGW or Cygwin, just for DevC++, codeblocks, VisualStudio, and make with CMD not netbeans.PD: Thanks for the response!

Comment: Use the ones with codeblocks to guide you. There will be differences but it's not that difficult to find the equivalents of the two IDE's.